# kendo ui: no Data in Subgrid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm working with kendo ui to create rich user interface, but i'm stuck t the following:
I want a Grid with a subgrid, the first one displays customer info, like name, etc the second shows the available shipping-adresses, the customer saved. Now my problem is, that in the subgrid is not data, although firebug shows, that the data was returned. This is my source:

```
$(function() {
var main = $("#customer-grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport:{
            read      :"data/users.php",
            update    :{
                url :"data/users.php?action=update",
                type:"POST",
                data: function (data) {
                    data.birthday = kendo.toString(data.birthday, "yyyy-MM-dd");
                    return data;
                    }
            },
            destroy:{
                url :"data/users.php?action=destroy",
                type:"POST"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "data",
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: {editable: false},
                    activated: { type: "boolean" },
                    birthday: {type: "date"},
                    gender: {defaultValue: "W"}
                }
            }
        }
    },
    height: 250,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    detailInit: detailInit,
    dataBound: function() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    },
    columns: [{ 
                field: "id",
                title: "ID",
                width: "50px"
            }, { 
                field: "gender",
                title: "Geschlecht",
                width: "100px",
                values: data
            }, {
                field: "firstname",
                title: "Vorname"
            }, {
                field: "lastname",
                title: "Nachname"
            }, {
                field: "birthday",
                title: "Geburtstag",
                width: "100px",
                format: "{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"
            },{
                field: "mail",
                title: "E-Mail"
            },{
                field: "activated",
                title: "Aktiviert",
                width: "100px",
                values: actval                  
            }, { 
                command: ["edit", "destroy"], 
                title: "&nbsp;", 
                width: "210px" 
            }],
            editable:{
                mode: "popup"
            }
});
});

function detailInit(e) {
    $("<div/>").appendTo(e.detailCell).kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: "data/adress.php?uid="+e.data.id
            },
            serverPaging: true,
            serverSorting: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize:6
        },
        scrollable: false,
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "id", width: 70 },
            { field: "zipcode", title:"Ship Country", width: 100 },
            { field: "city", title:"Ship Address" },
            { field: "street", title: "Ship Name", width: 200 }
        ]
    });
}
```

The function gets its data from a php page, which does a mysql-query and then gives back the data as application/json. But nothing is shown.

Hopefully you guys can help me.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works fine.

Check:

1. `e` parameter format. I've used: `detailInit({ detailCell : $("#grid"), data : { id : 1}});`
2. JSON returned by `data/adress.php`. I've returned:

> ```
> [
>     {"city":"Madrid", "id":"1", "zipcode":"31000", "street":"my street 1", "number":5},
>     {"city":"Sofia", "id":"2", "zipcode":"32000", "street":"my street 2", "number":4},
>     {"city":"London", "id":"3", "zipcode":"33000", "street":"my street 3", "number":3},
>     {"city":"San Francisco", "id":"4", "zipcode":"34000", "street":"my street 4", "number":2},
>     {"city":"Berlin", "id":"5", "zipcode":"35000", "street":"my street 5", "number":1}
> ]
> ```

Using the following (hardcoded) php response:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$named_array = array(
    array("city" => "Madrid", "id" => "1", "zipcode" => "31000", "street" => "my street 1", "number" => 5),
    array("city" => "Sofia", "id" => "2", "zipcode" => "32000", "street" => "my street 2", "number" => 4),
    array("city" => "London", "id" => "3", "zipcode" => "33000", "street" => "my street 3", "number" => 3),
    array("city" => "San Francisco", "id" => "4", "zipcode" => "34000", "street" => "my street 4", "number" => 2),
    array("city" => "Berlin", "id" => "5", "zipcode" => "35000", "street" => "my street 5", "number" => 1)
);
echo json_encode($named_array);
?>
```

**EDIT**: This is the definition of the grid containing the subgrid.

```
var outer = $("#outer").kendoGrid({
    dataSource:{
        type:"json",
        transport:{
            read:"names.php"
        },
        pageSize:5
    },
    sortable:true,
    columns:[
        { field:"id", width:70 },
        { field:"name", title:"Name", width:100 },
        { field:"lastname", title:"LastName", width:100 },
        { title:"Address", width:300, attributes:{ class:"ob-address"}}
    ]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

and then on a button click, I run:

```
$(".ob-address", outer.tbody).each(function (idx, elem) {
    detailInit({ detailCell:elem, data:{ id:1}});
});
```

As you can see I marked a column in the `outer` grid with a CSS class named `ob-address` and the function selects all the cell in the body of the `outer` table for inserting the inner table (subgrid).

Comment: Is that code within another grid? i've looked in firebug, and the request is sent, and an answer is received, but not processed and shown. i'll edit my first post, to sho the complete source, maybe that helps more

Comment: Yes it is. What I did is loading the inner grid in a cell of the outer grid. How do you trigger this load? For simplifying it, I trigger it with a button and I marked the cell with a class name as shown in the **EDIT**.

Comment: could you maybe upload you project as zip somewhere? I'm freakin out. I exactly took the Hierarchy-example from the Kendo-demos, but when i try to change the original url for my one, and to adjust my columns, nothing works anymore...

Comment: i just figured out my mistake. I was looking for my mistake in the javascript-code, because i thought my mistake was there, but i actually made the mistake in my php-script at formatting the json string. thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you find it! Good luck on your project! (Removing link...)